# The space of ("super")maps from a reversed-parity tangent bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, supermanifolds

Let $T[1]X$ denote the reversed parity tangent bundle of some smooth manifold $X$, i.e. the super/graded manifold such that the global sections of its structure sheaf are differential forms on $X$. I'm in principle interested in graded manifolds ($\mathbb Z$-grading) rather than supermanifolds ($\mathbb Z_2$-grading) but I think the difference is immaterial here.

I am interested in the space of maps $\mathcal E^{T[1]X}$ from $T[1]X$ to some (graded) vector bundle $\mathcal E$, $$\mathcal E\to M$$ where $M$ is the body of $\mathcal E$.

**My question is the following:** In the literature it is apparently claimed $\mathcal E^{T[1]X}$ has a fairly concrete description as the space of smooth maps $f_0:X\to M$ alongside a collection of (degree-shifted) differential forms on $X$ valued in the vector bundle $f_0^\star \mathcal E$. Is this known? Does this make sense?

For one such claim see e.g. the review paper
[AKSZ-BV Formalism and Courant Algebroid-induced Topological Field Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0608150)
on the AKSZ construction by Roytenberg, page 11 bottom. He considers only a degree-preserving map in $\mathcal E^{T[1]X}$ (for a specific $\mathcal E$, denoted $M$ in his notation) which he resolves into a map of  ordinary smooth manifolds $X\to M$ alongside two vector-bundle valued forms, altogether what he denotes $(X,A,F)$. (There is a notation clash with respect to this post.)